# Android studio - onClick attribute "give class or interface expected" error on Button element

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

In Android studio 1.3.2, i want to add an "onClick" attribute to a Button pointing to the clickMediaCheck, located in activity class:

```xml
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/checkMediaExistence"
    android:id="@+id/btCheckUrlExistence"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="clickMediaCheck"/>
```

This method is implemented like this in the .java corresponding to this activity:

```java
public void clickMediaCheck(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The problem is i've an error message "class or interface expected" in the xml describing the activity. I use no fragment.
The strange thing is i can build and test my app and the method is well triggered when I click on the button : the Toast display good.
The second strange thing is I can add the `onClick` attribute to other type of View like `EditText`, `Checkbox` and so on without problem. The problem seems to be only with `Button` element (i've not tested with all views)

Comment: The problem remains with the new 1.4.0 version, released these days

Answer (score 0):

your code is ok. I tested it. It worked without any problem.

Comment: I know this. I think it's a bug of Android studio

Answer (score 0):

Problem no more exists with v 2.1